# Modifying Search Page Template in Drupal 7

Tags: search, drupal-7

I am setting up a search page in Drupal 7 and when I click on Search something after entering a keyword, it just shows me an empty `page.tpl.php`. page. In other words, it just shows me the `page.tpl.php` template with no result in it.

It is actually surprising for me. The search page is not supposed to show `page.tpl.php` template but it is showing that template. I enabled Search module and `search-result.tpl.php` and `search-results.tpl.php` is in my theme folder; but still it is showing me `page.tpl.php` template. When I remove `page.tpl.php` however, it works perfectly. Any idea why this is happening? –

Is there a way to fix it? Why is it happening? How can I just create a search page template (like page--search--results.tpl.php) and it just reads that?

Many Thanks

### Page.tpl.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Theme implementation to display a single Drupal page.
 *
 *
 * @see template_preprocess()
 * @see template_preprocess_page()
 */
?>

<div class="wrapper">
<!--Header-->
  <header>
    <div id="top">


      <?php global $base_url; ?>
      <div id="logo">
        <?php if ($logo): ?>
          <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>"><img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" /></a>
        <?php else: ?>
          <?php if ($site_name): ?>
            <h1 id="logo-text"><a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>"><?php print $site_name; ?></a></h1>
          <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

      </div>


      <div id="searc"> <img src="<?php echo $base_url."/jkl/".$directory ?>/images/MK.jpg" id="mk" width="227" height="51" border="0" alt="Company Company">
        <form class="lmksearch">
          <input type="search" name="s" value="" class="searchbox">
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>


    <!-- Menu -->
    <div id="menu">
     <?php if ($main_menu): ?>
      <div  class="nav">
        <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
          'links' => $main_menu,
          'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'main-menu-links',
            'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
          ),
          'heading' => array(
            'text' => t('Main menu'),
            'level' => 'h2',
            'class' => array('element-invisible'),
          ),
        )); ?>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>


    <!--menu--> 
  </header>
<!--Header END-->

<!--content-->
<div class="c"></div>
<div class="content-wrapper">

  <div class="teaser-content-cat">

    <div class="page-title">Publication: <?php print $node->field_category['und'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name; ?></div>

    <!-- White Canvas on Black Starts here -->
    <div class="content-canvas">

        <div class="article-node left left-side">

          <!-- article would come here -->
          <h3><?php echo $node->title; ?></h3>
          <p class="teaser-content-desc"><?php print $node->field_month['und'][0]['value']; ?> | <?php print $node->field_author_s_['und'][0]['value']; ?> </p>

          <p>
              <div class="content-from-admin">

                <?php if ($search_results) : ?>
                    <?php include "search-result.tpl.php" ; ?>    
                <?php endif; ?>

                <p class="article-subhead"><?php print $node->field_subtitle['und'][0]['value']; ?></p>
                <?php echo $node->body['und'][0]['value']; ?>
              </div>

          </p>


        </div>

        <!-- Side bar --> 
        <div id="viewrow" class="right right-side">

            <?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>

        <!-- Sidebar -->  
        </div>


        <!-- Clearing Both Left and Right Floating Elements. -->
        <div class="c"></div>

        <!-- View Row Ends -->
        </div>

    <!-- White Canvas Ends -->
    </div>

    <!--Footer-->
    <div class="footer">
        <?php print render($page['footer']); ?>
    </div>

  <!-- Teaser Ends -->
  </div>

<!--Wrapper end-->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Clear caches. Also, check the syslog for any errors if you already did that.

Comment: did that many times. It just sternly ignore it.syslog also is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [template suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) for Drupal 7.

If you need to change the whole page template you have to use **page--search.tpl.php** or **page--search--node.tpl.php** respectively (if your path is /search/node). Because *search-results.tpl.php* is the default wrapper for search results inside page not for the page.

---

Edit after the submitted page.tpl.php code:

You are missing the `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` in the page.tpl.php file! Please follow the [Drupal Theming documentation guide](https://drupal.org/documentation/theme).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The problem is that when it goes into page--search.tpl.php, it just keeps on showing that the results are not found; even when I copied the exact code of `search-results.tpl.php` in the the `page--search.tpl.php`. Any suggestion here?

Comment: The page.tpl.php has any modifications? If statements, custom variables etc to print content?

Comment: I don't think so, but I added the page.tpl.php in my question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you copy pasting stuff from other tpl.php files into page.tpl.php? It seems that you have node.tpl.php and other tpl files combined into page.tpl.php. Is that true?

Comment: Yes. I copied from somwhere and used it here. Strange when I go back to bartik theme or a normal theme, everything works. and it has page.tpl.php and everything just like me. There is something that I am doing here that is screwing everything

Comment: Yes, see my modified answer. You are using the tpl.php files wrong way (In fact you are not using them at all).

Comment: Wow! How was I even running the theme then! :/ Thank you very much!

Comment: A Question; when I use `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` and I click on the single page; I wanna tweak how an article is shown. As in, I would want to show some custom variables, etc. etc. How would I change the layout and just output the body, custom variables and titles separately?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35172/discussion-between-theodorosploumis-and-steve)